# Cohomological proof of Wedderburn's theorem on the finite division algebra

Tags: finite-fields, homological-algebra, group-cohomology, brauer-group

Wedderburn proved that any finite division algebra is a field. I saw a beautiful proof which uses class equation and some basic analysis in the book *Proofs from the Book*. However, I want to know whether we can prove the same result by using the cohomological argument and the Brauer group.

By using Hilbert's theorem 90 and the Herbrand quotient, we can show that $H^{2}(\mathrm{Gal}(l/k), l^{\times})=0$ for any finite extension of finite  fields  $l/k$. (In fact, $H^{r}=0$ in this case.) Since $\mathrm{Br}(l/k)\simeq H^{2}(\mathrm{Gal}(l/k), l^{\times})$, we have $\mathrm{Br}(l/k)=0$ for all $l/k$ and so $\mathrm{Br}(k)=0$ for all finite field $k$. I think this should prove the Wedderburn's theorem, but I don't know how to proceed from here. Could you fill the gaps? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess the vanishing of the Brauer group means a finite division algebra is of the form $M_n(k)$ for some $n$. But it is a division algebra, so necessarily $n=1$ and it is a field.

Comment: @awllower Thank you very much! It is very simple.

Comment: @awllower By the way, do you know why classification of central simple algebra is important? Is there any special reason for this, or it is important just because classification of mathematical objects are important?

Comment: @awllower Did you mean $D\simeq M_{n}(l)$ for some finite extension $l$ of $k$?

Comment: @See-WooLee One perspective is that Galois $H^2$ is super important because it tells us what sorts of extensions the field can have, which is in some sense the answer to the oldest problem in number theory (solving Diophantine equations). Now the Brauer group gives us a super concrete description of that Galois $H^2$ group, and since cohomology is a slippery thing, we'll take any concrete description we can get!

Comment: @hunter But then above argument shows that any division algebra over $k$ is isomorphic to $k$, isn't it?

Comment: @See-WooLee I misunderstood your comment. Yes, you need the modification as you have in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think awllower's arguement can be modified in this way:

Let $D$ be a finite division algebra over $k$ and let $l$ be its center. Then $D$ is a central simple algebra over $l$, so we can consider $[D]\in \mathrm{Br}(l)=0$. This implies $D$ splits over $l$, i.e. $D\simeq M_{n}(l)$ for some $n$. 
Since $M_{n}(l)$ can't be a division algebra for $n\geq 2$ (we can find explicit zero divisors easily), so $D\simeq M_{1}(l)\simeq l$.